Power Query - Add column with path for each file
I have two queries (working) hat do exactly what I want:

they scan a folder for DBF files with a particular name
convert each one into a table
combine the tables into one long table

I want to add a column to the table with the path, so that I know which DBF file each one came from.
Here is the working code:
Main Query:

let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\..."),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".dbf") and ([Name] = "Point source.dbf")),
    #"Added MyPath" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "MyPath", each Text.TrimEnd([Folder Path],"\")),
    #"Added MyFile" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added MyPath", "MyFile", each Text.Replace([Name],[Extension],"")),
    #"Get Tables" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added MyFile", "fnGetDBF", each fnGetDBF([MyPath], [MyFile])),
    #"Combine Tables" = Table.Combine(#"Get Tables"[fnGetDBF])
in
    #"Combine Tables"


fnGetDBF Function
let
    Source = (MyPath, MyFile) => let Source = 
Odbc.DataSource("dsn=dBASE Files", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    Database = Source{[Name=MyPath,Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    Table = Database{[Name=MyFile,Kind="Table"]}[Data] in Table
    // Add MyPath as column here??
in
    Source 

I have tried:
let
    Source = (MyPath, MyFile) => let Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=dBASE Files", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    Database = Source{[Name=MyPath,Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    Table = Database{[Name=MyFile,Kind="Table"]}[Data] in Table,
    Table = AddColumn(Table, "FromPath", MyPath)
in
    Source

Which runs but the output is the same, i.e. the "FromPath" column is not added. How/where can I add this column?

Does this work?
let
    Source = (MyPath, MyFile) => 
      let Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=dBASE Files", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
      Database = Source{[Name=MyPath,Kind="Database"]}[Data],
      Table = Database{[Name=MyFile,Kind="Table"]}[Data],
      Table2 = Table.AddColumn(Table, "FromPath", each MyPath) 
      in Table2
    
in
    Source


Thank you! Yes it tries to add a column - though MyPath as a variable does not work on its own as the argument is supposed to be a "columngenerator" function -I'm still tyring to get it to work

I'll update now. See if that works

Óle! Yes it does. I was trying each [MyPath] and variations on that.
